# Pyplot: Control texts clip in one direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to change the plot window extents on an annotated plot to "zoom" into a certain window of interest. My text annotations fall outside of the plot window. If I use `clip_on = True` then all the text is hidden, but I just want to trim the text outside of the x-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
y = [3,2,5,9,6,7]

plt.plot(x,y)
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.text(x[i],11, '%d' %y[i])    
plt.axis([0,5,0,10])
```

**Full data:**

[image]

**Reduced window:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't fancy at all, but it works for `x_max` 1 to 10:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
y = [3,2,5,9,6,7]

x_max = 5 

plot_axis = [0,x_max,0,10]

if plot_axis[1] == x[-1:][0]:
    range_set = range(len(x))
else:
    try:
        x_idx = x.index(plot_axis[1])
    except: 
        x_idx = x.index(plot_axis[1]-1)  
        
    range_set = range(x_idx+1)
        
plt.plot(x,y)
for i in range_set:
    plt.text(x[i],11, '%d' %y[i])    
plt.axis(plot_axis)
plt.show()
```

Note: There isn't a sanity check for `x_max` = 0 or >10 implemented, but from your `plt.axis([0,5,0,10])` it seems you had this in manually in check anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it does so by not plotting the entire set of annotations. Ideally all text annotations would be added at once then just shift the window to make different subplots, e.g., `plt.axis([0,3,0,10])`, `plt.axis([3,6,0,10])`, `plt.axis([6,10,0,10])`.

I was able to "solve" the problem by adjusting the `set_visible` property of the texts for each window, but that's still less than ideal.

Comment: @Blink Thanks for the feedback. Just to check my understanding: You are kinda looking for a plot to be done, and then so to say slice the displayed range? (not that I have currently an idea how that could work)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do! Don't spend too much effort on it, I've sorted it out, just not elegantly (or how I imagined doing it).